# How can i find the control type in UIPath

Tags: c#, .net, uipath

i am using UIPath in visual studio and i am able to get the current focused element but i want to know the Control Type like whether it is TextBox or button etc.,

By using this i am select particular element form the screen and i am get its details in uiNode Object but how can i know the control type.

```
 WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
 uiNode.SelectInteractive(UiSelectionType.UI_SELECT_NODE);
 listBox1.Items.Add(new CapturedActivity { UiNode = uiNode, ActivityDetails = uiNode.GetSelector(true) + Environment.NewLine });
 WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way of checking the type of a control.
What you can do is, depending on the subsystem of the control, check the attributes that determine the type. For example: if the subsystem is java you should check the role attribute, if the subsystem is webctrl you should check the tag and type attributes, and so on.

To retrieve an attribute's value, you can use GetAttribute method

Comment: sry but i am new to this. can you just show me example.currently iam doing like this   string role = uiNode.GetSelector(true);
                if (role.Contains("button"))
                {
                    PerformeClickEvent(role);
                }
                else
                { //Performe insert }